# vsftpd не проходит авторизация локальных пользователей

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vps, vsftpd

Доброго времени суток!

Ранее я настраивал ftp на VPS и сохранял все команды для повторной настройки. Но ftp сервер на этот раз не хочет даже авторизировать а если авторизирует локального пользователя то говорит что "нет доступа к этой папке" или "сервер ftp не дал ответа". Я использую такие команды:

```
sudo mkdir /home/www
sudo mkdir /home/www/file
sudo mkdir /home/www/node
sudo mkdir /var/www
sudo mkdir /var/www/node
sudo chown -R root:rootgroup /home/www/file
sudo chmod 775 /home/www/file
sudo chown -R root:rootgroup /home/www/node
sudo chmod 775 /home/www/node
sudo chown -R root:rootgroup /var/www/node
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/node
sudo chmod a-w /home/www
```

`/home/www` - Общий каталог

`/home/www/node` - файлы сайта (в эту папку монтируется каталог /var/www/node)

`/home/www/file` - хранение некоторых данных.

При авторизации пользователей с группы `rootgroup` он должен получить доступ к созданию папок и файлов в папках `file` и `node` и удалению всего не считая эти каталоги.

Файл конфигурации:

```
listen=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

local_root=/home/www

pasv_min_port=40000

pasv_max_port=50000
```

В /etc/shadow пользователи под которыми я пытаюсь залогиниться имеются.

Помогите с настройкой ftp. Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, попробуйте:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/www
sudo chmod 755 /var/www
```

И еще,

`vsftpd` сбрасывает свои права до залогиниваемого пользователя? Работает от своего пользователя? От `root`? Сам `vsftpd` имеет доступ к этим каталогам?

Comment: После ввода команд которые вы указали выше и редактирования файла конфиг все заработало! Я убил на это все около 12ти часов))) Уже все перелазил) Отредактирую вопрос и добавлю туда код конфига. Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @АртурФранк Пожалуйста. Обратите внимание на права к `www`: `755`, возможно "доступ на чтение для всех" (локальных пользователей) - это не то, что вам нужно, в этом случае стоит установить права на `750`.

Comment: Я временно поставил 777

Comment: Лишь бы понимал, что делаешь. https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-izmenit-prava-dostupa-v-linux

Comment: В итоге решил установить права доступа такие `root:rootgroup 770` для каталога `/home/www/node` (чтобы доступ к этому каталогу имели только администраторы) / а для каталога `/home/www/file 775` (Чтобы другие пользователи имели доступ к ftp каталогу но не могли туда загружать данные только скачать)